# Debate on using heavy duty java rest service on docker, should we switch?

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

As we are moving on docker, the first thing we tried is to run our existing (`tomcat+java rest service + mysql server`) app in a `docker container`. We tried to restrict our app (on `tomcat` level and on `docker` level), to use only `512` MB of `RAM`. We failed! tomcat could not launch the war file as it was short of enough memory. So we ran it without any limit, great, it launches the app. So the team is now debating on, should we move on and write app in some new light weight platform(`Golang, jetty etc.`) or try to optimize the existing app. 
The question here is, are we using `java` incorrectly or the combo itself is so memory eater(`tomcat-8 + java 1.8 on fedora OS`)?
I know the question is too vague, but I need some discussion to start thinking  in right direction as We(the team) are too new to `docker` and I'm sure we have never looked at `Java` from performance perspective(we are happy to have a cross platform easy to learn and use language). ;)
I'll appreciate any thought that comes on this topic.

Comment: Why that harsh 512 MB restriction? Do you know the actual mem footprint of your stack?

Comment: If you restrict the container to 512MB you would need to restrict Xmx to 128MB or less which is not very much. Why dont allow more memoryfor docker (`-m 2G`)? If a rewrite makes sense depends on the complexity of the service and the experience you have with the other language. If you need a low footprint service you could also invest some time to prune down the Java application. If that does not work changes are other runtimes need the same memory.

Comment: You should also pt mysql in its own container if youwant to restrict resources this hard.

Comment: Not exactly! we are just trying to launch it in a restricted environment. As it is just a rest service with some database operations, it shouldn't take much memory. As we are, in near future, wants to run small rest services(multiple on same server instance) on low configuration rpi kinda devices, we need to learn either JAVA in restricted env. or some other. platform. That's the startup thought for us.

Comment: As others already commented various points , With latest trends around , you can combine tomcat + java web service using spring boot and deploy it as a single docker image. secondly, Golang is a very option as it removes the JVM dependency and I have seen lot of products are developed using golang in recent times.